# Proving a Simple equation

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

I have a not so smart question; but I just cannot figure it out !

Suppose that I have a real $2 \times 2 $ matrix $(a_{ij})$ of non-zero determinant,

and let $z \in \mathbb{C} $ be such that $ \Im(z) >0$.

I need to show that $ a_{21}z +a_{22} \neq 0$.

I am stuck doing the same thing over and over again with no result.

Help, please!

Comment: Key fact is that the $a_{ij}$ are real, I suppose.

Comment: @ccorn Definitely! Thanks... I fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that
$$
a_{21}z+a_{22}=0.\tag{1}
$$
Then there are two cases:

a. $a_{21}\ne 0$. In such case $(1)$ implies that 
$$
z=-\frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}\in \mathbb R,
$$
contradicting the fact that ${\mathcal{Im}}\,z>0$.

b. $a_{21}=0$. This implies that $a_{22}=0$, and thus the second row of the matrix is identically zero, which means that the determinant is also zero: a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $a_{21}z +a_{22}=0$

- the case $a_{21}=0$ gives $a_{22}=0$ so  $\det A=0$. Contradiction.
- hence $a_{21}\ne0$ and then $z=-\frac{a_{22}}{a_{21}}\in\Bbb R$. Contradiction with $\Im z\ne0$. Conclude.